# Table width issue, html css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have made a table of which does not fill the full width of the parent div in CHROME & SAFARI.

This works fine in Firefox but I would like to get working in all browsers.

After some views on here I found that in some chrome cases can be fixed with setting parent div to...

```
display: block; width: 100%;
```

.. but the issue persists.

Also found another couple cases where specifying no margin & padding so gave that a shot and still there are issues with displaying in Chrome & Safari.

**THE HTML**

```
<div class='player_box info_pic_2'> 
    <div style='display: block; width: 100%;'>
        <table style='margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0px; height: 30px;'>
                <tr class='border_bottom'>
                    <td>CELL A</td>
                    <td>CELL B</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        <table style='margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0px; top: 30px;'>
            <tr class='border_bottom'>
                <td>ROW A </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='border_bottom'>
                <td>ROW B </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='border_bottom'>
                <td>ROW C </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='border_bottom'>
                <td>ROW D </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='border_bottom'>
                <td>ROW E </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='border_bottom'>
                <td>ROW F </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**THE CSS**

```
tr.border_bottom td {
    border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
.info_pic_2 {
    position: absolute;;
    height: 250px;
    top: 130px;
    right: 70px;
    width: 350px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    color: black;
}
.player_box {
    border:solid 4px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 33px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:32px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:32px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:32px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:33px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:32px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:32px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:32px;
    border-top-left-radius:33px;
    border-top-right-radius:32px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:32px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:32px;
    text-align:center; background:#575757;
    padding:100px 50px 100px 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle for this:  http://jsfiddle.net/rcQmW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue appears to be the `padding` values in your `.player_box` selector (Second to last line on your CSS. Remove the padding and it will fill correctly.

Comment: Ha no worries! Just a helpful hint too, I try to keep my styling in the css as much as possible. It's so much easier to track these little things down when I'm looking in one place! Plus it makes it easier for the people on SO to help out here too.

Answer (score 0):

I can make it behave better by changing this CSS:

```
.info_pic_2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    top: 130px;
    right: 70px;
    width: 350px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    color: black;
}
```

to:

```
.info_pic_2 {
    height: 250px;
    top: 130px;
    right: 70px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    color: black;
}
```

I've found that mixing absolute positioning and percentage widths is a nightmare.

Edit: The padding doesn't help either, but see my updated version here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcQmW/2/

Comment: Cheers, didnt help with this case, found that i had padding values in the #player_box css which were causing the issue. Thanks for your help